# Normalize response body in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, httpresponse

I do have some entity class (code without annotations for simplified example)

```
class User {
   public String id;
   public String name;
}
```

Now I want to output this via an API, but I want to structure my response in a special format, like

```
{
  "data": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "mars3142"
          }, // user object or another entity or list...
  "meta": ...,
  "error": ...
}
```

The meta and/or error data should only be visible in special situations (like RuntimeExceptions). Where is the best place to transform my entity results into the normalized response? Do I need to write a filter for that? Does anybody has a sample code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72355056/708157 and transformed it a little bit.

Now my classes are that way

```
public class BaseResponse<T> {
  boolean success;
  T data;
  Error error;
}

public class Error {
  ...
}
```

And every api response is now `ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<XYZ>>`. This way, I can setup my default structure and my classes are lose coupled, because I can use every class for T within my `BaseResponse`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to implement something this:

```java
public abstract class BaseResponse {
    // Meta data 
    // Consider defining fields here needed for happy-path and error-responses
    // Contains common tracking fields, e.g. correlationId, requestId
}

public class ErrorResponse extends BaseResponse {
    // Error Fields
}

public class Response extends ErrorResponse {
    // Entity-object in your case
}
```

I guess you can build your response like setting response from DAO to above suggested structure in controller layer. For error-responses (in case of `RuntimeException`s), they're standardly build and returned in `@ControllerAdvice` or other.

Some patterns of exception handling are explained in [Error Handling for REST with Spring | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring).

Comment: This was my first idea, but I don’t want to refactor the complete service, if the structure of data, meta and error is changed. A solution to alter the response entity before sending back to the client would be better, I guess. And I like the spring boot framework for attaching/annotate classes to do things. So I‘m able to add functions on the fly. Your solution is too coupled for my usecase.

Comment: @hc_dev My bad, That's `@ControllerAdvice`. I usually like to name the class as GlobalExceptionalHandler

Comment: @mars3142 Agree, huge updates to contract is not really easy after development and pain point to get API clients to agree.

Comment: I extended your solution to a more flexible response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73023736/708157

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your 2 questions:

1. Design: The proper place for this response-mapping depends on the scope (all responses or just some) and existing components in your application's response layer.
2. Patterns and Web-Framework concepts: I would not use the response-filters or -interceptors of your web-framework. Those should be used for cross-cutting concerns, or for chained processes (e.g. security, authorization, enrichment, sanitation).

Instead I would use the web-frameworks concepts and components that are responsible for response-representations, like `ResponseEntity` (HTTP-response representation, `ControllerAdvice` (error-handling), `HttpMessageConverter`.

---

There are 3 ways you could "wrap" your objects into uniform JSON-response models:

1. Annotate class with the custom [`@JsonRootName`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#6-jsonrootname) as `data` and in special cases add `meta` and/or `error` attributes (through e.g. embedding into a wrapper or using a mixin)
2. A JSON custom serializer that could extend from [`BeanSerializer`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/BeanSerializer.html) which wraps this and any class uniformly in your given outer structure
3. Modify Spring's [`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) to wrap any returned response object into the predefined JSON-structure

You could iterate from the simplest (1.) to the most complex (3.). Some iteration code (like 2.) can be reused in the next (3.).

#### 1. Use a Wrapper Class

The first is rather a simple start where you can implement the "normalization" within controller-methods. You could for example put the object (serialized as `data`) into the "empty" meta-structure (wrapper-class) with an empty `JsonNode`, and `meta` or `error` properties.

#### 2. Define a Custom Serializer

The second is pretty flexible and can be tested well in isolation (not even depending on Spring). It would allow to implement the complete object-wrapping in one place.

#### 3. Customize Spring's HTTP Message Converter

The third is similar to the second but requires some knowledge about Spring's message-converters and allows you to transform *each* response-object to a specific JSON-response using Jackson's `ObjectMapper`.

---

Sample code can be found online, e.g. at [Baeldung's Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/category/json/jackson/) or Spring tutorials, [Springframework Guru](https://springframework.guru/) articles.

Comment: This sounds like a way to go. Will test it. Thanks.